# how to accessout-of-box web scripts( alfresco) through web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, alfresco

Can you provide any sample code available to access out-of-box web scripts( provided by Alfresco) from web application
(login to alfresco, create folders, upload documents)
Web-Scripts is new for me. I am used to code using plain java API (Example Filenet API). Does Alfresco provide JAR files containing JAVA API which I can use for all repository operations like login,create folder,upload/download documents etc……..
My requirement is to create folders(spaces) in Alfresco through custom web application and upload documents to those spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can access out-of-the-box web scripts using the following URL (use your own host and port).

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/index
```

You can refer docs.alfresco.com for more Java, JavaScript APIs and all about Alfresco development.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can you provide any sample code available to access out-of-box web scripts( provided by Alfresco) from web application

As @Kintu said you can access the list of the Alfresco's out of the box webscripts using this URL:

```
/alfresco/service/index/all
```

And to make you own web script This [tutorial](https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html) is a good way to get started.
 From your web application you can consume them like any other plain old REST API.

> Does Alfresco provide JAR files containing JAVA API

Alfresco provides a rich set of [services](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/dev-services.html) that you can use in your web scripts.

> My requirement is to create folders(spaces) in Alfresco through custom web application and upload documents to those spaces

- To **create a folder** you can use this endpoint:

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/site/folder/{site}/{container}/{path}
```

The minimum request body is of the form:

```
{ "name": "NewNodeName" }
```

The full set of parameters accepted in the request is of the form:

```
{  
   "name": "NewNodeName",
   "title": "New Node Title",
   "description": "A shiny new node",
   "type": "cm:folder"
}
```

- To **upload files** you can use this endpoint (HTML form data):

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/upload
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-UploadUploadPost.html) for more informations about this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting with API Explorer, later on you can always use something not documented as nicely as this is.

https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

As someone who is already familiar with Filenet maybe you are already familiar with CMIS? That is probably the easiest way to create folders and documents in Alfresco. There are a number of CMIS clients available at [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/), including OpenCMIS, which is a Java client.

You can find a bunch of [code samples](http://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/) at the Apache Chemistry web site as well.

One advantage of using CMIS to do this is that CMIS works on a variety of repositories, not just Alfresco. Why go to the trouble of learning an Alfresco-specific REST API when there is already an industry standard? Learn it once and use it often.